# how to add condition in variable?

Tags: javascript, variables

```
function() {

  var product = productrev || productrev2;

  var productrev = document.querySelector("#checkout > div > div > div.col-sm-7.col-md-7.col-lg-7.col-xl-5.checkout-details-main > div > div:nth-child(5) > div.col-md-6.text-right").innerText;

  var productrev2 = document.querySelector("#checkout > div > div > div.col-sm-7.col-md-7.col-lg-7.col-xl-5.checkout-details-main > div > div:nth-child(6) > div.col-md-6.text-right").innerText;

  return product;

}
```

if productrev is true it should be returned with the data but if it is undefined it should be returned with productrev2, can anyone correct my variable, please ??

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exEv8.png)

Comment: You're trying to assign the result of your variables condition to `product` before you've even declared them.

Comment: javascript programs generally run in sequence, top to bottom, not bottom to top

Comment: how to declared them?

Comment: Is it like this?
function() {

    var productrev = document.querySelector("#checkout > div > div > div.col-sm-7.col-md-7.col-lg-7.col-xl-5.checkout-details-main > div > div:nth-child(5) > div.col-md-6.text-right").innerText;

  var productrev2 = document.querySelector("#checkout > div > div > div.col-sm-7.col-md-7.col-lg-7.col-xl-5.checkout-details-main > div > div:nth-child(6) > div.col-md-6.text-right").innerText;

var product = productrev || productrev2;
  return product;

}

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
function() {
    
      var productrev = document.querySelector("#checkout > div > div > div.col-sm-7.col-md-7.col-lg-7.col-xl-5.checkout-details-main > div > div:nth-child(5) > div.col-md-6.text-right").innerText;
    
      var productrev2 = document.querySelector("#checkout > div > div > div.col-sm-7.col-md-7.col-lg-7.col-xl-5.checkout-details-main > div > div:nth-child(6) > div.col-md-6.text-right").innerText;
    
      return (productrev ? productrev : productrev2);
    
    }
```

If you are new to programming concepts like conditional operators and logical operators then go with simple conditional statements like if , else.

Also to be sure your variables have values inside them I suggest logging them into the console so we have a better idea figuring out what is going wrong.

To make sure your variables have values inside it wait for the DOM to be constructed by putting your code inside onload listener like follows.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
 
    var product;
    var productrev = document.querySelector("#checkout > div > div > div.col-sm-7.col-md-7.col-lg-7.col-xl-5.checkout-details-main > div > div:nth-child(5) > div.col-md-6.text-right").innerText;
    
    var productrev2 = document.querySelector("#checkout > div > div > div.col-sm-7.col-md-7.col-lg-7.col-xl-5.checkout-details-main > div > div:nth-child(6) > div.col-md-6.text-right").innerText;
    
    if(productrev){
    product = productrev;
    }
    
    else {
    product = productrev2;
    }

    console.log(productrev);
    console.log(productrev2);
    console.log(product);

    return product;
    
});
```

Comment: It's returning with "undefined"

Comment: Try logging the variables into the console using console.log(). Check if those variables point to the required elements of the DOM. I think they both are undefined and that is why you are getting "undefined" in the end

Comment: it is showing this when I typed debuger:

(function(dataLayer) {return (function(){document.querySelector("#checkout \x3e div \x3e div \x3e div.col-sm-7.col-md-7.col-lg-7.col-xl-5.checkout-details-main \x3e div \x3e div:nth-child(6) \x3e div.col-md-6.text-right");debugger;var a=document.querySelector("#checkout \x3e div \x3e div \x3e div.col-sm-7.col-md-7.col-lg-7.col-xl-5.checkout-details-main \x3e div \x3e div:nth-child(4) \x3e div:nth-child(6)").innerText;debugger;return productTax2?productTax2:a})();})([]);

Comment: function() {
    
      var productrev = document.querySelector("#checkout > div > div > div.col-sm-7.col-md-7.col-lg-7.col-xl-5.checkout-details-main > div > div:nth-child(5) > div.col-md-6.text-right").innerText;
    
      var productrev2 = document.querySelector("#checkout > div > div > div.col-sm-7.col-md-7.col-lg-7.col-xl-5.checkout-details-main > div > div:nth-child(6) > div.col-md-6.text-right").innerText;
    console.log(productrev);
console.log(productrev2);
      return (productrev ? productrev : productrev2);
    
    }

Run it and see what is on the console.

Comment: I checked there is data in productrev2 but with this variable, it is returning with "undefined" something wrong with the condition ??

Comment: No the condition was correct already. you were declaring your variables incorrectly.

Comment: where to check it in console?

Comment: press f12 on your keyboard it will popup a window at the bottom then click on the console tab. or right click in your browser and click "Inspect Element" and then go to console tab.

Comment: Oh I see can you help how to correct my  variables, when I enter only that variable which have data it is returning with correct data but when I apply condition it is returning with undefined .

Comment: I opened the console but not find anything related to this

Comment: Still undefined

Comment: Edited the answer again . I want you to run the code and post a screenshot of your console by editing your question alright.

Comment: screenshot uploaded

Comment: we are logging all the variables that are declared and it shows undefined which means the variables you have declared are not pointing to the correct elemtents. Try adding document.onload listener so that your function runs only after the DOM has been constructed(Edited the answer).

Comment: How to add document.onload listener in my variable?

Comment: Error at line 2, character 9: Parse error. 'identifier' expected

Comment: try removing the function() keyword from line 2 (Edited answer for you)

Comment: Thanks a lot but still undefined I am tired :(

Comment: Lol Javascript is always tiring ! I think your query is wrong . try giving the elements in your HTML an id and then use document.getElementById() to retrieve the values instead of using querySelector.

Comment: @KashanHussain To avoid continuing this discussion any further in the comments, please edit your question so that you have a [mcve] (include html structure). This answer correctly addresses the primary issue of your code, but judging by this discussion here, it still doesn't work as intended.

Comment: @Calculuswhiz  OK noted Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = () => {
    // put all of your code here
}
```

Comment: Some more explanation is warranted. E.g. "Query selectors are only valid after the page loads," or something.